# Logical negation of the Brocard's conjecture

Tags: logic, prime-numbers

Let $p_{k}$ and $p_{k+1}$ are consecutive prime numbers greater than $2$.

The Brocard's conjecture states that:

**Conjecture**: For all $k≥2$, there are at least four prime numbers between $p^2_{k}$ and $p^2_{k+1}$.

My **question** is: How one can logically negate this conjecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To approach this problem, let us first translate the question into a statement in first-order logic. This is the usual language which one uses when considering mathematical statements. If we let the relation $P(k)$ stand for the statement there are at least 4 prime numbers between $p_k^2$ and$p_{k+1}^2$ and let $T(k)$ represent the statement that $k\geq 2$, then the statement can be represented by the following first-order formula where $\to$ represents the logical connective “implies":

$$\forall k(T(k)\to P(k))$$

Now, once we have translated this conjecture into a first-order formula, we can apply the mechanical rules of first-order logic to negate the statement using the following logical equivalences where $\leftrightarrow$ is the logical connective “if, and only if” and can be thought of as meaning “is equal to."

If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are formulas in a first-order language, then:

1. $\lnot\forall x\phi\leftrightarrow \exists x\lnot\phi$
2. $\lnot (\phi\to\psi)\leftrightarrow (\phi\land\lnot\psi)$

Applying the above two rules to our first-order formula $\forall k(T(k)\to P(k))$ we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\lnot\forall k(T(k)\to P(k))&\leftrightarrow \exists k\lnot(T(k)\to P(k))\\
&\leftrightarrow \exists k (T(k)\land \lnot P(k)).
\end{align*}

Therefore, we find that the negation of our formula $\forall k(T(k)\to P(k))$ is logically equivalent to $\exists k (T(k)\land \lnot P(k))$ and we can translate this statement back into English using our interpretations of the relations $T(k)$ and $P(k)$ as, “There exists some $k$ where $k\geq 2$ and where it is not true that there are at least 4 prime numbers between $p_k^2$ and$p_{k+1}^2$." I trust that you realize that the negation of, "there are not at least four prime numbers between $p_k^2$ and$p_{k+1}^2$” is equivalent to saying that, “there are less then four prime numbers between $p_k^2$ and$p_{k+1}^2$,” and, using this, our statement:

“There exists some $k$ where $k\geq 2$ and where it is not true that there are at least 4 prime numbers between $p_k^2$ and$p_{k+1}^2$.”

can be simplified to the more natural:

“There is some $k\geq 2$ where there are less than four primes between $p_k^2$ and$p_{k+1}^2$.”

As you can see, the hard part is effectively translating our statement into a first-order language. Once this is done, we can apply the mechanical rules of first-order logic to find an appropriate formulation for the negation of the statement, which can then be re-translated into English.